# script which starts another script as another user, how to remove su process?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, su

I have a bash script on Fedora Linux, which I run as root user, which starts another script as less privileged user `rpmbuild`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# start as another user, fork
su rpmbuild -c ./long.sh &
# disown  the job
disown
# run some other long running things.
```

Content of `long.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 300
```

Now what happens if you do a `ps aux`:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        67  0.0  0.0  81884  4080 ?        S    12:42   0:00 su rpmbuild -c ./long.sh
rpmbuild    68  0.0  0.0   9512  2340 ?        Ss   12:42   0:00 /bin/sh ./long.sh
rpmbuild    69  0.0  0.0   4316   628 ?        S    12:42   0:00 sleep 300
```

How can I get rid of process 67, the `su rpmbuild`, so that only the `rpmbuild` process remains?

Or do I need another tool?

It would be nice, if these `su` (a lot of them in the process list) would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can run sudo (or su - ) pkill 67  and/or use  sudo su - $(username)  to run it which should automatically disown and de-escalate the permissions of the script(s), however while that script or any children are running it WILL show short of a --nohup iirc.